# Can I add an ethernet card so I can use one to connect to my internet router and the other to connect to another PC using a crossover cable?

Tags: ethernet

I have a Windows 10 Home PC with an RJ45 connector. I want to add a second ethernet card so I can use one to connect to my internet router and the second ethernet port to another PC using a crossover cable. Will this work?

Comment: Yes it should work.

Comment: an important question is what you're trying to do. It'll work but additional config may be needed - whether its a point to point connection or data sharing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work, if properly configured.  You probably dont need a crossover cable, as most modern ethernet devices are auto-sensing.  Auto-sensing means it can detect a direct connection and use a standard ethernet cable and the device does the crossover itself.

Answer (score 0):

It would require careful work with the routing table.
The second adapter needs to be set to an IP address that is not in the
range of the first adapter.

To work, the other computer will also need its own secondary network card,
since, if connected to the router, it will have a wrong IP address
which is in the range of the first adapter.